# Postgres - Insert data into table from nested json

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to insert nested json data into a table (users) if the record does not already exist in that table.  I am passing in json data from an API to the Postgres function fn_update_users_test.  The data represents new users of my application and contains the data I want to insert into the users table (if the record does not already exist).  In the insert statement, I am trying to use json_populate_recordset but am falling well short of anything that works.  Help and you are on my Christmas list!  :)

value of the p_userlist parameter (JSON data) that is passed in from the API-

```
 [{"kind":"admin#directory#user","id":"107135403825787437500","etag":"\"mZ6zy6fy8dMbMO7K4FrHYhYwAYXvzlQcofJtEqj2VHI/q1RDqamBEi9qC6fodTrbYDOka8g\"","primaryEmail":"John@acme.com","name":{"givenName":"John","familyName":"Doe","fullName":"John Doe"},"emails":[{"address":"John@acme.com","primary":true},{"address":"John@acme.com.test-google-a.com"}]}
```

The table I am trying to insert into is-

```
 CREATE TABLE public.users
(
userid bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
firstname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
lastname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
phone character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
isemailenabled boolean DEFAULT false,
ptorate integer
)
```

and the function is-

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_update_users_test(
p_userlist json)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

with customer_json (doc) as (
  values 
 (p_userlist::json)
)
insert into public."users" (firstname, lastname, email, phone, isemailenabled, ptorate)
select l."name"->givenName, l."name"->familyName, l.primaryEmail, l.phone, FALSE, 0
from customer_json l
cross join lateral json_populate_recordset(null::public."users", doc) as p
where l."primaryEmail" not in (SELECT email FROM public."users");
      
RETURN 1;
```

END;
$BODY$;

How do I fix the function so that it parses and then inserts the data into the users table?  Thanks!

Comment: With json_each(json) you can select from p_userlist:  select * from json_each(p_userlist). If you are trying to parse the email to confirm it's not a duplicate you can select the email only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you give me an example of how to modify the query in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  My error was in the syntax.  Using "->" was the right way to access the nested elements of the json, and extracting the value should have been "->>".  I had a few other issues, but in short, the following sql works perfectly-

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_update_users_test(
p_userlist json)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
 AS $BODY$
 BEGIN
drop table  IF EXISTS userlist;
drop table  IF EXISTS newusers;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE userlist (
firstname text,
lastname text,
email text,
phonearray text,
isemailenabled boolean,
ptorate integer default 0
);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newusers (
firstname text,
lastname text,
email text,
phone text,
isemailenabled boolean,
ptorate integer default 0
);
insert into userlist (firstname, lastname, email, phonearray, isemailenabled, ptorate)
SELECT (sub.element->'name'->>'givenName')::character varying as firstname, 
(sub.element->'name'->>'familyName') as lastname,
(sub.element->>'primaryEmail') as email, (sub.element->'phones'->0->>'value') as 
phone, false, 0
FROM 
 (SELECT json_array_elements(p_userlist) as element) as sub;
--insert new users
INSERT INTO public."users" (firstname, lastname, email, phone, isemailenabled, 
ptorate)
select firstname::character varying, lastname::character varying, email::character 
varying, phonearray, isemailenabled, ptorate
from userlist ul where ul.email not in (select email from public."users");

RETURN 1; -
drop table userlist;
drop table newusers;

END;
$BODY$;
```